# PowerShell how to change the users default PSModulePath

Tags: powershell, console

My work network folder creates a problem with PowerShell Module Paths on my work laptop. They use caching of the home folder; while on the work network, my actual files are synced to my local disk so that I can access offline, and any changes I make offline are synced back up when I am back on the corporate network. In $env:PSModulePath, I have

```
\\ad.xxx.net\WPS\XX\P\UD\200024\UserName\Home\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

When I connected to the corporate network, this works fine, but when I am offline, starting PowerShell *always* attempts to connect via the UNC path, which fails until it times out, so starting a PowerShell console takes more than 20 seconds every time.

To try and fix this, I have changed `PSModulePath` in `HKCU\Environment` to an equivalent of the above on the C: drive (`C:\Users\UserName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`) but this fails and everytime a PowerShell console starts, it always tries to access to find that Module path via the network and always times out / fails / 20+ second startup time.

Is there a way that I can remove the default user Module path, or redirect to the C: drive to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the PSModulePath using this(completely new value)

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath",[System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator + "Your Path", "PC name")
```

Or this(Keeping the old value):

```
$CurrentValue = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "PC name")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", $CurrentValue + [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator + "Your path", "PC name")
```